# Ubuntu 18.04 LTS - Upgrading prevented by a package needing reinstall

Tags: 18.04, apt, package-management, upgrade, dpkg

18.04 LTS AMD 64bit HP-Pavillion
When trying to upgrade to 20.04, the system says:

```
Failed to load the package list
This is a serious problem. Try again later. If this problem appears again, please report an error to the developers.
E:The package linux-headers-4.15.0-126 needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
```

But, unfortunately, I couldn't manage to install or reinstall the package.
The system keeps giving the same message:

```
azevedo@HP-Pavilion:~$ sudo apt-get install -- reinstall linux-headers-4.15.0-126
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: The package linux-headers-4.15.0-126 needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
azevedo@HP-Pavilion:~$ uname
Linux
azevedo@HP-Pavilion:~$ uname -r
4.15.0-126-generic
```

Comment: Boot to a prior kernel and see if you can update that way.

Comment: Current is 4.15.0-136, which is why apt cannot find the older -126 version in the archives anymore. [Download it from launchpad.net](http://launchpadlibrarian.net/508615577/linux-image-4.15.0-126-generic_4.15.0-126.129_amd64.deb) in order to reinstall it...in order to remove it.

Comment: Ok, thanks.  I downloaded it to my computer now.  Could you help me write the correct command in oeder to install it?